# GIT - Ignore file again

Tags: git, github

This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
*.iml
*.conf
```

So I forced to add a file named `settings.conf` and now I want Git stop tracking changes on this file.

I tried with `git rm --cached settings.conf` but it removes the file from git repository. I want this file to stay on git repository but do not detect changes.

I also tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged settings.conf` and got : `fatal: Unable to mark file settings.conf`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have check "git exclude" project/.git/info/exclude options, it might help you, however, if you place it on the exclude file it will be just in your machine.

Comment: @RomainValeri I have tried that solution. I edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the command `git update-index --assume-unchanged settings.conf`

If you want to commit a change to the file, then you will need to toggle this setting using `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged settings.conf`, make your commit, and then repeat the first command.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: This is *not* what `assume-unchanged` is for. Git doesn't have any perfect way to do what OP wants, but `skip-worktree` is closer than `assume-unchanged`. In particular, `assume-unchanged` _does **not** prevent Git from seeing changes_. It's [actually the very opposite](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqy4z5go1y.fsf@gitster.dls.corp.google.com/): instead of saying, "hey, Git, I'm going to change this but you should just ignore it" it says "hey, Git, _I promise I won't change this file_".